# Finding a way to post when there is a specific channel point redeem on twitch to my discord server

Tags: powershell, discord, windows-10, webhooks, twitch

I am trying to find a way to let my Discord server post the data when a channel point redeem gets triggered on a twitch channel.

i could not find a direct way of doing it, so

i used a 3rd party chat bot (called chatty) to log the messages to a log file on my local windows 10 machine

then used a script on windows powershell to post a message using webhooks on discord, the thing is the script posts "File: C:\Users\AYYA.chatty\logs\2023-12-09_highlighted.log Changed" and not the actual data of the log file's last line.

which looks something like the following

example: "[2023-12-09 04:26:54 AM][#Testrider] MOD|SUB/12  @ELCabager There are 1x Eevee in the wondertrade pool! (0x ✨)"

---

the script that was used is below

```
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "C:\Users\AYYA\.chatty\logs"
$watcher.Filter = "2023-12-09_highlighted.log"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

$action = {
$path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
$changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
$log = "File: $path $changeType"
$webhookurl = "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/1182854675947593799/DHgRfZWP547WkDUrwG9LuGtwNrWLs51o6Z0CmgqLa0Gh_jtUmeDj9qxmhvPNOV8_dOkx"
$body = @{
    content = $log
} | ConvertTo-Json
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $webhookurl -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType 'application/json'
```

}

```
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName Created -Action $action
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName Changed -Action $action`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the actual data of the log file's last line, read it using [`Get-Content` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) as follows:

```
$content = (Get-Content -Path $path -Tail 1).ToString()
$body = @{
    content = $content
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked perfectly, i have an additional question, the posting is not instant as i hoped, it took a long time to post on the DC server, any idea why?

Comment: Please ask at https://superuser.com/ for your  additional question.